# Does the mac 2D Quartz support multichannel (CMYK+spot colors)

Tags: objective-c, macos, quartz-graphics

I found the quartz 2D just supports standard color spaces(CMYK, RGB...).
I want to deal with images for printing. Does it support multichannel color space?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. There are a few third party solutions you might want to take a look at though. For example:

[PDFLib](http://www.pdflib.com/products/mobile-and-embedded/pdflib/)

[Debenu](http://www.debenu.com/products/development/debenu-pdf-library/)

None of them free, unfortunately.